# Using Jetpack carousel w/o creating a gallery

Tags: images, gallery, plugin-jetpack

I want to use the Jetpack Carousel for all my posts without editing all of them. Is there a way to show pictures in the carousel even if they're not in a gallery?

Comment: Let me know, if this is more a Stackoverflow related question.

Comment: No, it isn't. Just see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another better solution: This displays only the first image in a gallery, linked to launch the carousel. You would make that first image, and it's caption, clearly indicate it as a link to a gallery.

Give gallery an HTML ID:

```
<div style="display:none">
[gallery include="111,222,333"]
</div>
```

Then add CSS:

```
#gallery-link .tiled-gallery-item { display: none; }
#gallery-link .tiled-gallery-item:first-child { display: block; }
```

*Note: .tiled-gallery-item is the class inserted by Jetpack when Settings> Media> Image Gallery Carousel is set to Tiled Galleries.*

---

*Here's old original answer, which has some value, and works fine when launching a gallery on another post, but not on same post:*

This is tested, but NOT rigorously; seems to work: write the shortcode with the images you want (attachment IDs); put it in post, but don't display it:

```
<div style="display:none">
[gallery include="111,222,333"]
</div>
```

Then you can trigger the Carousel w/ a href URL that looks like:

```
http://examples.com/your-post#jp-carousel-111
```

where "111" is the ID of the first image attachment ID you want Carousel to start with.

Comment: Unfortunately this link only triggers the gallery once. Subsequent clicks fail. A better solution is to use a `render_block_core/image` filter to wrap `<img...`s in `<a...` tags with `href` pointing at `get_attachment_link()` and add the same url on the `<img...` as `data-permalink` property too. This way JP Gallery script will pick up the image as a native one and include it in a gallery as designed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to show pictures in the carousel even if they're not in a gallery

*Afaik*, this isn't possible. JetPack doesn't collect all your `<img>` tags in a post. It converts the default `[gallery]` shortcode.